# Ubuntu 14.04. Wireless MEDIATEK Corp. MT7630e not working

Tags: 14.04, wireless, realtek

The indicator applet does not display wireless as an option. I tried to unplug the wired connection and try the wireless one. Still Indicator applet does not display wireless Icon.

The results of the script given here 
[My wireless/WiFi connection does not work. What information is needed to diagnose the issue?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos)

is as below

http://paste.ubuntu.com/11222145/

Comment: Still, +1 for including the WiFi diagnostics right away.

Comment: I don't think this is _quite_ a duplicate.  This from his wireless info suggests that he has already compiled the 7630E driver once: `# PCI device 0x14c3:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.2/0000:08:00.0 (rt2800pci)` He either needs to simply re-compile or, if there were errors at _make_, we need to troubleshoot. I'd like to hear from @Gaara and possibly re-open.

Comment: I found this link in one of the comments above 
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1220146/comments/125 
This contains the exact details of what I did to get it working. Thanks to the community.