# Ubuntu 14.04: MediaTek Wi-fi problem

Tags: 14.04, networking, wireless, realtek

After the problem mentioned here

[Ubuntu 14.04. Wireless MEDIATEK Corp. MT7630e not working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/625573/ubuntu-14-04-wireless-mediatek-corp-mt7630e-not-working)

is resolved, (Wifi connected and it was working fine until next reboot) Now the Wifi connection is being displayed in the indicator applet. But Laptop is unable to connect to it.
The necessary configurations are available in this link

http://paste.ubuntu.com/11237335/

Kernel log when I click on the network to connect as below

http://paste.ubuntu.com/11237508/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A significant factor is this:

```
seetha:Infra, <MAC 'seetha' [AC1]>, Freq 2462 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 52 WEP
```

Wireless encryption using WEP is not only difficult to connect to, but also quite insecure. WPA2-AES is preferred; not any WPA and WPA2 mixed mode and certainly not TKIP. Second, if your router is capable of N speeds, you may have better connectivity with a channel width of 20 MHz in the 2.4 GHz band instead of automatic 20/40 MHz, although it is likely to affect N speeds. I also have better luck with a fixed channel, either 1, 6 or 11, rather than automatic channel selection. Also, be certain the router is not set to use N speeds only; auto B, G and N is preferred. After making these changes, reboot the router.

Next, I recommend that your regulatory domain be set explicitly. Check yours:

```
sudo iw reg get
```

If you get 00, that is a one-size-maybe-fits-all setting. Find yours here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-2 Then set it temporarily:

```
sudo iw reg set IS
```

Of course, substitute your country code if not Iceland. Set it permanently:

```
gksudo gedit /etc/default/crda
```

Use nano or kate or leafpad if you don't have the text editor gedit. Change the last line to read:

```
REGDOMAIN=IS
```

Proofread carefully, save and close the text editor.

Next, I'd set IPv6 to Ignore in Network Manager: http://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/18/html/Installation_Guide/images/netconfig/network-connections-ipv6-ignore.png  This example is for ethernet, but you want wireless.