# Problem with specific WiFi connection after suspend or poweroff from button

Tags: 14.04, wireless, dual-boot, drivers, uefi

I am new in Ubuntu and I have a problem with my WiFi connection.
I have installed **dual boot** UEFI, Windows 8.1 and Ubuntu 14.04.
Initially I had a lot of problems because WiFi do not work out of the box. This bug is described here: [**bug descriprion**](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1220146). My Network controller is **MEDIATEK MT7630e 802.11**.

After almost a year of waiting appeared a solution described in posts [#244, #240]. The solution initially worked well for a few hours, but then I realized that if I **poweroff** my laptop(HP ProBook 450 G1) from the power button or **after suspend** then can not connect to my WiFi again. Interestingly, there is another Free WiFi (no password) to which I connect without any problems. Same as my phone HotSpot (with password). Tried all settings (even our longer remember how many things I've tried). But WiFi was working when it wants.

Finally, I found solution: boot Windows and then restart and Boot Ubuntu again. So I'm connected to my WiFi. Currently, it works and I not make any adjustments, because I afraid to lose again 2-3 days trying to make WiFi working. On the other hand I do not like this behavior of the system and believe it is possible to be repaired. Do you have any ideas how?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to login Windows an turn off Fast Startup then restart login to Windows again. Afterward, shutdown windows and login Ubuntu to see if it is solved.

Here is how you can turn off fast startup on windows :http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/6320-fast-startup-turn-off-windows-8-a.html

I'm not sure if it might help, but give it a try. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I tried this, but the problem is still present. I set fast startup on again because boot too slowly.

Answer (score 0):

I found solution that works for now. I changed my wireless security from **WEP** to **WPA to WPA2 Personal** (WPA-PSK/WPA2-PSK, AES, encryption). I know that WEP is weak, but this was by default and I have never had problems with this settings under Windows 8.1.

I dont know why this solution works, but if someone can explain it will be awesome.

[This post](https://askubuntu.com/a/626092/456939) helped me to think about the type of connection and reach a solution.